# Populating a sectioned UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Ok, this question has probably been asked a couple of times but I can't quite find an example that helps me getting forward.

I'm trying to create a sectioned UITableView that acts as some sort of history: it should be populated by an NSMutableArray that consists of HistoryBatchVO objects. Those HistoryBatchVO objects contain a timestamp (NSDate) and a names array (NSMutableArray) which in turn contains objects of type NameVO that contains (among other) a NSString.

I'd like to use the timestamp as the sections header and the strings from NameVOs to be filled into the sections in the table accordingly.

In my table controller I have:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_dataModel.history count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

(Note: _dataModel.history is my NSMutableArray of HistoryBatchVOs).
... but I suppose **numberOfRowsInSection** needs to return the number of objects in my HistoryBatchVO.names array. Question is how do I do that?

Also, how do I change the implementation for **cellForRowAtIndexPath** to get this working?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    HistoryBatchVO *batchVO = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

---

**UPDATE: After solving the issue, Here's the working code:**

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_dataModel.history count];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    HistoryBatchVO *h = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:section];
    return [h.names count];
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    HistoryBatchVO *h = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:section];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", h.timestamp];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    HistoryBatchVO *batchVO = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NameVO *nameVO = [batchVO.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = nameVO.string;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: NSLog `_dataModel.description`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `names` is an array and with some more assumption of data types, the program skeleton will be something like this, but you have to accommodate with your needs.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_dataModel.history count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    HistoryBatchVO * h = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:section];
    return [h.names count];
}
```

You need also to implement the section title things, but I think you will like to format the dates using `NSDateFormatter`.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     HistoryBatchVO * h = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:section];
     return h.date;
}
```

The cell element will be something like this,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;       
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ( cell == nil)
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] UITableViewCellStyle:UITableViewCellStylePlain reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    HistoryBatchVO *batchVO = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NameVO * nm = [batchVO.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = nm.name

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try to adapt your example! However the numberOfRowsInSection now throws an error: [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]

Comment: if your numberOfSectionsInTableView return [_dataModel.history count] then the numberOfRowsInSection method should always get something at [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:section]. There may be something wrong with that.

Comment: When I log out the count of my _dataModel.history it says 4 which is correct. Logging the section numbers in numberOfRowsInSection it shows 3, 0, 1, 2 ... so they are not in order. Could that be related to the error?

Comment: That depends the order the table cells are drawn and reused. UITableView is a scrollview and when you scroll with touch different sections are drawn on the screen. NSLog ("%@", _dataModel.history) to see the elements there.

Comment: Hooray it's working now! The error wasn't caused by numberOfRowsInSection but by titleForHeaderInSection: I've accidentally used HistoryBatchVO *batchVO = [_dataModel.history objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];